# How to search for a pattern in a sequence of chars?

Tags: java

How would you set up a nested loop to search a sequence of chars for every occurrence of a pattern? This is what I have so far, but it's only showing one occurrence and giving an indexoutofbounds error. How can I fix it?

```
int i = 0; 
while (i < data.size()) { 
    if (patternString.charAt(0) == data.get(i)) {
        i++;
        int j = 0; 
        while (patternString.charAt(j) == data.get(i)) { 
            j++;
            System.out.println(j) ;

            if (j == patternString.length()) {
                System.out.println("Found pattern " + "at index " + (i));
            }
        } 
    } else { i++;} 
}
```

Comment: have you considered using a regular expression?

Comment: Can you provide input and expected output? Please also read [mcve].

Comment: HINT: Shouldn't `j` be set equal to 0 each time you start looking for the pattern again?

Comment: take a look at [regex](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: the input is a list of characters,  but say the input was AGGTATGGTATG the output should be found at 3, found at 8

Comment: Both your `if` branch and your `else` branch increment `i` with 1. You can move that statement.

Comment: Please don't delete your code in your question. It's useful for others who may come along later so that they're not confused by what the initial problem was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're likely getting an IndexOutOfBounds error because of not checking whether `i` and `j` are within bounds before accessing `data` and `patternString`.

There are more consice ways to do this as mentioned, but if you still want to do the pattern search "manually", you can try this:

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) { 
    if (patternString.charAt(j) == data.get(i)) {
        while (j < patternString.length() && i < data.size() && //indices checks
                   patternString.charAt(j) == data.get(i) ) { 
            j++;
            i++;
        }   
        if (j == patternString.length()) {
            i -= patternString.length(); //set i back to the start of the pattern
            System.out.println("Found pattern " + "at index " + (i));
        }
        j = 0;
    } 
}
```

Comment: that works perfectly apart from when a character before the pattern is the start of the pattern, eg if the pattern is start and the sequence is ssstarttt it wont pick up the start

Comment: @user10168997 not sure I get why it's not working with you. If I run the code here with `data` being "ssstarttt" and `patternString` being "start", it outputs the index as 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `String#indexOf`:

```
int index = 0;
while (index != -1) {
    // this line replaces your code
    index = data.indexOf(patternString, index);
    // a result of -1 means pattern was not found
    if (index != -1) {
        System.out.printf("%s found at index %d%n", patternString, index);
    }
}
```